# Can't render a component on top of another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a view that should have a title and a list of items. I generate the list of item components using Lodash/_.map. It looks like this:

```
prepareEnrollmentsRender = () => {
    return (
        <Header {...this.c('overviewTitle')}>Current enrollments</Header>,
        _.map(this.TEST__enrollments, 
            (enrollment, index) => (
                <Enrollment
                    enrollmentName={enrollment}
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    onSelect={() => {this.onEnrollmentPress(index)}} />
            )
    ));
}
```

And then in the render I call the function to render everything. The problem is that the Header component does not appear. I render them like this:

```
render = () => {
    <View>
        {this.prepareEnrollmentsRender()}
    </View>
}
```

***Note: This React app is being developed within a framework, so some unknown components like Header are valid internal components, as well as things like {...this.c()}, etc. Those are NOT part of the issue.***

Comment: You mean `Enrloment` - s are appearing but not `Header`? or non of them?

Comment: Can you please explain about `return (<Header> ...</Header>, _.map(...))`? Why do you have a comma `,`?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen Yeah that's just me going total paranoid and trying invalid stuff. I'm going to try to wrap it inside a parent div. And Edward, only the Header component doesn't appear

Comment: @erol_smsr if wrapping in div doesn't help I suspect that your `Header` component has `isVisible` some prop like that and  `this.c('overviewTitle')` method might return an object which has something like this `{ ... isVisible: false}` and that's y you are not seeing the header. If you could post the `Header` component I will have a look

Comment: No that's not the case fortunately. I just had to wrap it inside a view and curly braces and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the output of `prepareEnrollmentsRender`  in an extra div surrounding both Header and the Enrollment array, or (possibly) try wrapping both in an array. You're returning two comma separated values. That's not valid.

Comment: This did the trick. I wrapped the code in curly braces and wrapped them in a parent div. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Sometimes when you work with the same code too long it becomes hard to see the details. I've been there many times :D